# how to get javascript values into asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview

Hi i have two javascript values and i want to store that values in the gridview so hows this is possible

Comment: i want that details to be stored in the database (MYSQL) so how can we store

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your database with values in javascript then you can use **[AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))**. Issue a POST request to the server and call your desired method from your code behind file.

***Edit***

You can build an XMLHTTPRequest object and using its different methods you can build a post request.

You can start from here

**[Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest)**

If you can use a framework like jQuery it has lot of inbuilt function for performing ajax tasks. Take a look at **[jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)**.

Comment: but give me example of that ajax example of posting